# Extract informations from excel file if a certain column is not empty

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to extract some informations from an excel file using python and openpyxl. I'm learning it so I don't know at all the language. I've writed this code that will extract data from the excel file and will print it to the console.

```py
# Importing openpyxl
import openpyxl
# loading excel file
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("BEVANDE.xlsx")
# loading active sheet
ws = wb.active
# looping sheet for values
for row in ws.values:
    for value in row:
        print(type(value))
```

The output is something similar, and for certain extracted informations like this output I will have also a fourth parameter that is a price variation.

```
80369691
VITASNELLA ACQUA ML.1500
0,28
-0,01
```

Using the `type()` function I'm able to see that all the output is a string.
What I need to achive is to get only the product that will have a price variation like the example. What I need to do with the string and how I can achive my scope using and if statement?

Comment: Python doesn't automatically recognize the type, so everything is string. You can try using `float()` to convert `'32'` to float `32.`, however `float('spam')` will raise a `ValueError` exception.

Comment: Openpyxl reads a cell [depending on the value](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/cell/cell.html?highlight=datetime%20int%20float), either string, float, int or datetime. Therefore a cell with integer value will be type int, a cell with text will be type string, a cell with a decimal number will be type float and a cell with Excel formatted date will be type datetime.

Comment: For your example, assuming for the last two the comma is a decimal point, the cell values should be; <class 'int'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, however if for example `80369691` is formatted as TEXT in the cell then it will be read as a string.

Comment: As a solution I've used the tuple that will be provided by the row variable and selected the indexes of the data I will need.